# Column 'id_training' in on clause is ambiguous

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to show course_title data but I get:

> 'id_training' in on clause is ambiguous.

Where is the error in the query?

```
CREATE TABLE `examination` (
`id_exam` int(32) NOT NULL,  
`class_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`id_training` int(32) NOT NULL, 
`id_question` int(32) NOT NULL,
`total` int(3) NOT NULL,  
`exam_duration` int(5) NOT NULL,
`start` datetime NOT NULL,
`end` datetime NOT NULL,
`passing_grade` int(3) NOT NULL,
`id_user` int(32) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `training` (
`id_training` int(32) NOT NULL,  
`course_code` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`course_title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`training_time` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Query:

```
SELECT e.id_exam
     , e.class_name
     , e.id_training
     , e.total
     , e.exam_duration
     , e.start_exam
     , e.end_exam
     , e.passing_grade
     , t.course_title 
FROM examination e
INNER JOIN training t
ON id_training = course_tilte
```

Comment: Qualify your columns, e.g. `examination.training`.

Comment: try this -> inner join training on examination.id_training = "course_title"

Answer (score 2):

The Reason for this Error "Column 'id_training' in on clause is ambiguous"
is same column exist with same same in both of the table so due to this on specifying the 
id_training column in where clause sql got confused from which table i should take so always specify with alias name.

```
SELECT e.id_exam
     , e.class_name
     , e.id_training
     , e.total
     , e.exam_duration
     , e.start_exam
     , e.end_exam
     , e.passing_grade
     , t.course_title 
  FROM examination e
  JOIN training t
    ON e.id_training = t.id_training
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.id_exam, e.class_name, e.id_training, 
e.total, e.exam_duration, e.start_exam, 
e.end_exam, e.passing_grade, t.course_title 
FROM examination e
INNER JOIN training t  
ON e.id_training = t.course_title
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks incorrect. It should be like this:

```
SELECT examination.id_exam, examination.class_name, examination.id_training, examination.total, examination.exam_duration, examination.start_exam, examination.end_exam, examination.passing_grade, training.course_title 
FROM examination 
INNER JOIN training 
ON training.id_training = examination.id_training
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this ON:

```
ON t.id_training = e.id_training
```